# How do I turn on a Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM monitor?

Tags: display

How do I turn on my brand new Samsung SyncMaster 2494HM monitor?

I can't seem to turn it on. There's a row of monitor control symbols on the bottom right (including the universal I-in-the-O power symbol), but no distinct physical button. I suspect it has some sort of proximity sensor. I've tried pressing on the symbol, on the frame on the below, and on the case behind. Still nothing

- I've got it plugged in. I've checked the power cable is seated properly.
- I have the video cable connected. Double checked both ends.
- I've checked the outlet with another device.

Before I pack it up and take it back to the store, is there anything else I've missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a power switch on the back next to where the power cord plugs in on that model.

Comment: Ah yes... the black rocker switch on a black background, that's only visible when you put your head on the desk and look up. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Hate to be a killjoy, but did you look in the manual? It's probably expained there ;-).

Comment: Manual... what's a manual.

Yah, it's in there in one of the diagrams, but it wasn't obvious until you knew there was a second hidden power switch. My wife looked at the document to and saw nothing. Of course the trouble shooting guide (and the tech support person at Samsung) failed to indicate that as well, and went straight on to "press the on button on the bottom right hand corner of the screen".  What was wrong with physical switches in plain view vs a switch that will only ever be flipped by turning the monitor around.

Comment: So it has a "soft-power" switch on the front panel, and a "real" power switch that is very well hidden? That's indeed a problematic design...